# Promise async/await que não se resolve

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, async, promises, async-await

Estou fazendo .map() em um array, para fazer uma query Mongoose/MongoDB com cada elemento desse array e retorna um outro array com os resultados.

Porém, após esse processo, eu tento acessar o novo array com console.log(novoArray) e o que imprime é [object Promise], e eu queria os resultados das queries que deveriam estar nesse array.
OBS: As queries deram certo (testei com 1): cada uma é salva na variável value. Vejam abaixo:

```
async function buscarNoBdPorValorContido(model, atributo, valor, resposta){
        var documentos = []
        var valores = valor.split(` `)
        documentos = await valores.map(async valor => {
            const query = model.find({url: {'$in': [new RegExp(`.*${valor}.*`, 'i')]}})
            let value = await query.exec()  //Tudo certo aqui
            return value
        })
     
        console.log('resultado '+documentos) //Imprime "resultado [object Promise]"
           
    }
```

Resumo da história, eu quero usar o array documentos cujo conteúdo deve ser os resultados das queries.
Estou há horas nisso, não sei mais o que tentar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema aqui é que você está retornando objetos do tipo `promise` para o método `map`.

Entenda que apesar de você estar declarando a função de callback como `async`, o método `map` não está preparado para esperar pela resolução de promises, logo ele irá continuar iterando sobre os outros itens do array antes mesmo da resolução do seu `await`.

Um método nativo do JavaScript para esperar pela resolução de todas as promises de um array é o `Promise.all` (como já mencionado).

Após gerar o seu array de promises...

```js
var documentos = valores.map(valor => {
    const query = model.find({url: {'$in': [new RegExp(`.*${valor}.*`, 'i')]}})
    return query.exec() // não precisa utilizar await aqui, não terá nenhum efeito prático
})
```

Você pode aguardar a resolução com o método

```js
var resultados = await Promise.all(documentos)
console.log(resultados)
```

Porém para o seu exemplo, eu imagino que seria mais eficiente criar um array de expressões regulares e então fazer apenas uma chamada para o banco de dados:

```js
var valores = valor.split(' ')
var expressoes = valores.map(val => new RegExp(`.*${valor}.*`, 'i'))
var query = model.find({ url: { $in: expressoes } })
var documentos = await query.exec()
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado! Nem todo herói usa capa kkk

Comment: @Lucas, fiz uma revisão na resposta, considere utilizar ela.

Answer (score 1):

Promise dentro de um map precisam se resolvidas com Promise.all()

Você usou await fora do map pra fazer todas as queries.

No caso teria que envolver toda a as queries do map dentro de um promise.all.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo? Acho que sua explicação não ficou clara para alguém que não está muito familiarizado com promises.

Comment: Um instante pessoal, vou testar.

Comment: @RodrigoAzevedo Poderia me mostrar?

Comment: @RodrigoAzevedo Mas cada query estava sendo feita dentro map em   let value = await query.exec(), então eu tiro esse trecho? Eu simplesmente dou return query dentro do map?

Comment: @RodrigoAzevedo  como ficaria o await? É que eu quero usar a solução das promises ainda dentro dessa função, pra poder retornar esses valores pra fora dela